# Why n$\times$n identity matrix is the only matrix that is orthonormal, symmetric, and PD?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Here is my thoughts, but I am not sure whether they are correct...

Since A is symmetric, then A = A^T. Also we know it is square and orthonormal, A^T * A = I.
Therefore with these two facts, we know A^2 = I.

Then I can get two possible solution: A = I or A = -I. Since for a PD matrix, all eigenvalues should be positive, therefore A cannot be -I, the only solution is A = I

Appreciate any helps!

Comment: Not quite. $A^2 = I$ says that the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^2 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)$. Since this splits (over any field), $A$ is diagonalizable by a standard criterion. The eigenvalues are each $\pm 1$, but since $A$ is positive-definite, the eigenvalues must all be $1$, so $A$ must be similar to the identity matrix, i.e. $A = I$.

Comment: got it, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A^2=I$ does not imply $A=\pm I$.  It implies that $A=A^{-1}$ and many matrices do that.  For example, the real matrices
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$
for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $A^2=I$.  (h/t:  Ben Grossman)

Comment: As an example, we have the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&t\\0&-1}
$$
for any $t \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for the good class of examples.  I'll add to my answer.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out!